# Can JSONP module of Angular 2 be forced to read MIME type ('application/json')?

Tags: json, angular, jsonp

I'm calling a SonarQube API using JSONP module.

```
this.jsonp.get('https://sonarqube.com/api/projects/index')
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

I previously used Http module of Angualar2, which caused the browser to throw the error

> Origin http://localhost:4200 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

To overcome this problem I found out that you could use `JSONP` or `CORS` or launch chrome with `--disable-web-security` of which I could find sufficient typescript support to get started with JSONP. But I later found that JSONP expects MIME-type to be application/javascript when I got the following error

> Refused to execute script from 'https://sonarqube.com/api/projects/index' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Is there a way to force JSONP module to fetch JSON data and parse it successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1: Enable JSONP in Server**

I found out that this isn't possible. JSONP is just one way to get over the `Cross-Origin-Requests problem`, but it requires a modification to the server configuration/implementation to serve JSONP data (`MIME-type: application/javascript`).

**Solution 2: Enable CORS support in server**

`CORS` is a more recent solution to the Cross-Origin-Requests problem. It can be resolved by adding the following headers to the server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Lang
```

**Solution 3: Using a reverse proxy**

One suggestion I came across in my search was to *use the server to fetch the Cross-Origin-Request*. I didn't have control over the server code. Then I came across the concept of [Reverse Proxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), found the [`cors-anywhere`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere) package in an angular forum. The reverse proxy fetches these resources on behalf of your front-end and adds the CORS headers to the proxied request.